# display newly added field value of account settings

Tags: entities, users

[image]I added a new field(First name) in Account settings under Configuration & its machine name is 'field_first_name' 
I am trying to load this value in home page like this

```
<?php print $user->field_first_name ?>
```

But the above code is not working. Please help. I debug $user and found that this value isn't there. What should I do to show the value of the newly added field in home page.

I've added screenshot.

Comment: You seems to first need to debug the `$user`, to do that: `dpm($user);` (if you have devel module installed), otherwise `echo '<PRE>'; print_r($user);`,  than you can check what is the exact name of field first name in the user object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [field_get_items](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7):

```
global $user;

$user_contaning_field = user_load($user->uid);

// Check if we're dealing with an authenticated user
if ($user->uid) {

  // Get field value from $user
  $field_first_name = field_get_items('user', $user_contaning_field, 'field_first_name');

  foreach ($field_first_name as $key => $value) {
    print field_view_value('user', $user_containing_field, 'field_first_name', $field_first_name[$key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: And better, use [field_view_value](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7) to get the value.

Comment: I am getting error message "Notice: Undefined variable: field_first_name in include() (line 31 of C:\xampp2\htdocs\Journal\themes\admin\templates\includes\admintoolbar.php)."

Comment: @SureshAlagar please try with updated answer

Comment: the reason it was not showing you field is $user used as arguments for "field_get_items" does not contain the field information.you to load the user so to have the field inside the user entity.

Comment: Thanks, arpitr. You have solved my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Made a small edit incorporating [`field_view_value`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7) as suggested by @ЕлинЙ.

Answer (score 2):

Small edit with @Beebee asnwer, since it seems he is not logged in so adding it as separate answer

```
global $user;

 // load the user entity so to pick the field from. 
$user_contaning_field = user_load($user->uid);

// Check if we're dealing with an authenticated user
if($user->uid) {

  // Get field value;
  $field_first_name = field_get_items('user', $user_contaning_field, 'field_first_name');
  if(isset($field_first_name[0]['value'])) 
    print $field_first_name[0]['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for starters

```
<?php 
    global $user;
    if ($user->uid) { // if registered...
      //get field value and print it
    }
```

Comment: I am getting an error message "Undefined property: stdClass::$field_first_name"

Comment: yeah its actually not the real code you need, is a start point, try to debug the $user object..., field_get_items below seems great

Comment: Hello. Code-only answers are rarely usable. If the code works, they don't tell what was the problem and why it works. If it does not, it's even worse as they provide neither reasoning nor solution.